# Readmore.js is not working

Tags: jquery, html, button, plugins, expand

I recently downloaded readmore.js, but it does not work. I might have forgotten something. The read more button does not appear and the full text is shown.

Here is what I have in the head tag:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Readmore.js/2.2.0/readmore.js"></script>
```

And in the body:

```
<div class = "article">     
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ullamcorper sapien eget ante porta eleifend. Aliquam enim velit, suscipit non lorem at, rhoncus sollicitudin arcu. Pellentesque blandit aliquet egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vel nisl magna. Mauris in consequat augue, quis vestibulum augue. Maecenas aliquam scelerisque nunc vitae scelerisque. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nam sit amet fermentum arcu. Fusce mollis a augue vel tempus. Etiam aliquet enim et felis congue sodales. Integer sit amet diam nec erat fermentum scelerisque. Phasellus elit sapien, placerat eu mi vitae, convallis pulvinar turpis.
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('.article').readmore();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is jquery (or other dependencies) loaded?

Comment: Did you check your console for errors?

Comment: I loaded jquery and I checked for errors. Nothing was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems your code inside the `<script>` block is wrong.

You have to make your `$('article')` either `$('#article')` or `$('.article')` (either ID or class selector)

```
<script>
    $('.article').readmore(); //if you want to use class selector
    $('#article').readmore(); //if you want to use ID selector
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you are referencing your `article` dom element with a class use `$('.article').readmore();` or otherwise if you're referencing it with an ID property the use, `$('#article').readmore();`. You need to place only one statement in the above answer according to your usage of DOM.

Comment: I have modified your code, Here is the working link, https://jsfiddle.net/f2fxgg8a/1/  Please ensure that you are including your `readmore.js` file after the inclusion of `jquery` and also, for `readmore.js` inclusion, please use this cdn url instead of yours, `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Readmore.js/2.2.0/readmore.js`

Comment: It did more, but look what happens:http://imgur.com/a/4IrQR. The "Read More" button is there, but it does not work. If I press it, the close button will appear, but the text will not move.

Comment: Did you remove your `<script src="js/readmore.min.js"></script>` and tried including `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Readmore.js/2.2.0/readmore.js"`</script> ?

Comment: I did. Same result.

Comment: Okay, Can you please paste your current HTML code update your post at the top?

Comment: Thanks for updating, Please update your jQuery inclusion too.

Comment: You need move your jquery inclusion above your readmore.js script inclusion.

Comment: Just incase if you are using **WordPress**, Have you tried the other workaround shared by **Rax Shah** given below?

Comment: I am not using wordpress. I did not see the post untill now. So blind...

Comment: I found the issue, It is the jQuery version which is misbehaving, Can you please try including this cdn url `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js` in place of your `js/jquery-3.1.0.js`  I have tested replacing and it is working

Comment: Glad that it worked, download those versions of jquery/readmore libraries and have it in your local in case if you don't want to use CDN

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to wordpress loading jquery in noconflict mode in which the $ shortcut does not work. Try to replace it with an explicit jQuery or wrapt the relevant code in a way which will decalre $ like in the following example

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('article').readmore();
});
```

Comment: Not using wordpress. Sorry for answering so late.

Answer (score 1):

Check out jquery migrate plugin. It helped in my case. Seems something wrong with compatabilities.
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js
Or play with different jquery versions and see if it help. :)

Comment: this was the case for me.